# Kotlin class delegation features

Tags: kotlin

This is how I know to create class delegation in Kotlin:

```
class CustomList<T>(private val data: ArrayList<T> = ArrayList<T>()) : List<T> by data
```

However, I do not want to put the data in the constructor, because I want the list to be empty when `CustomList` is created:

```
class CustomList<T> : List<T> by data { 
    private val data = ArrayList<T>()
}
```

This does not seem to be working.

How can I make the `data` an inner field and also delegate the List to it's methods without having to write all delegation methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Class Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) is currently only possible for parameters of the primary constructor.

Workaround: declare the primary constructor private and offer a public constructor that delegates to it.

```
class CustomList<T> private constructor(private val data: List<T>) : List<T> by data {
    constructor() : this(ArrayList())
}
```

Comment: Use `listOf()` instead of `ArrayList()`. There is no need to specify `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Joshua In general you're right, but OP's original code instantiates `ArrayList<T>()`.